# Why is my lightbox image not loading when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, lightbox, lightbox2

When I click on the image itself, the lightbox loads but the image itself doesn't - instead, all I see is a white box. Basically, the lightbox shows up, but the image doesn't load. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I watched a youtube video on how to create a lightbox and followed the steps exactly. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I included the links to the proper javascript and css files.

Please help!!

This is my html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description:" content="Image Gallery">
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Fiona Blumin" />
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="Welcome">
    <h1>My Travels through Europe</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="Pictures">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
            <img class="small-img" src="images/pic1 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic2.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
            <img class="small-img" src="images/pic2 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic3.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
            <img class="small-img" src="images/pic3 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic4.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic4 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic5.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic5 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic6.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic6 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic7.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic7 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic8.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic8 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic9.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic9 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic10.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic10 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic11.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic11 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="images/pic12.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery">
          <img class="small-img" src="images/pic12 copy.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[This how it looks when I click on an image in my gallery:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ej5.png)

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or snippit demonstrating the issue?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Jenni she's asking for a runnable https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can actually see whats happening.

Comment: Sorry, but it is just not possible to give any answer without seeing live page/demo. Maybe try alternative lighbox script, for example, http://fancyboxjs.com

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is the problem

> src="images/pic1 copy.jpg"

try to do it like this

> src="images/pic1copy.jpg"

and make sure you are targeting the right picture with the right path. Let me know if it works